# Fisheye Raycasting

Tags: c, raycasting, fisheye

I'm trying to build simple raycasting game. I'm rendering wall based on light length. Wall size is calculated based on natural log formula.
Problem is fisheye! I tries cos formula but it's not applicable to my architecture.
Here's the code:

```
void    draw_3d(t_cub3d *this, double len, int num_of_ray, double start)
{
double height;
double width;
double x;
double y;

height = 720 / log10(len + 1);
if (height > 720)
    height = 720;
width = 1280.0 / 640;
y = (720 - height) / 2;
while (y < height)
{
    x = 2 * num_of_ray;
    while(x < 2 + width * num_of_ray)
    {
        my_mlx_pixel_put(this, (int)x, (int)y, 0xfffff);
        x++;
    }
    y++;
  }
}

int raycast(t_cub3d *this)
{
double start = this->raycast->pa - this->raycast->fov;
double end = this->raycast->pa + this->raycast->fov;
double ray_p_x;
double ray_p_y;
double len;
int num_of_ray;

num_of_ray = 0;
while (start <= end)
{
    ray_p_x = this->raycast->px;
    ray_p_y = this->raycast->py;
    while (this->gameinfo->map[(int) ray_p_y / 30][(int) ray_p_x / 30] != '1' && this->gameinfo->map[(int) ray_p_y / 30][(int) ray_p_x / 30] != ' ')
    {
        ray_p_x += cos(start);
        ray_p_y += sin(start);
    }
    len = fabs(this->raycast->px - ray_p_x) / fabs(cos(start));
    len *= cos(this->raycast->pa - start);
    start += this->raycast->fov / 320;
    draw_3d(this, len, num_of_ray, start);
    num_of_ray++;
}
mlx_put_image_to_window(this->mlx_info->mlx, this->mlx_info->mlx_win, this->img->img, 0, 0);
return (0);
}
```

How to fix fisheye distortion if cos formula doesn't apply to my case.

[How it looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8irie.png)

[How it looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4b1Zy.png)

Comment: Ummm. What's your question?

Comment: How to fix fisheye distortion if cos formula doesn't apply to my case.

Comment: Does this help? https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/97574/how-can-i-fix-the-fisheye-distortion-in-my-raycast-renderer

How about this? https://www.permadi.com/tutorial/raycast/rayc8.html